# Celery stops execution of task when RabbitMQ clustor node is restarted or rejoins

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

We have one celery application which uses RabbiMQ as broker. We are facing following issue when one of the RabbitMQ node is restarted and joins the cluster again, celery stops execution of task even after queue data synchronisation is completed. More details are as followed.

Stack Details :

Number of nodes in cluster : 3

Docker - 25.0.3

Celery version - 5.3.1

Kombu version - 5.3.1

RabbiMQ Version - rabbitmq:3.12.10-management

RabbitMQ HA Cluster Policy :

- queue type - classic
- sync mode - automatic
- batch size - 20

[Celery stops task execution after this error received in RabbitMQ container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVJb6.png)